# sprintf not copying the right way

Tags: c, printf, bison

This is my code in Bison:

```
char str[200];
printf("$4 %s\n", $4);
printf("$1 %s\n", $1);
printf("$2 %s\n", $2->name);
sprintf(str, "%s %s, %s", $1, $2->name, $4);
printf("%s\n", str);
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
$4 int c
$1 int
$2 b
int b, int b,
```

I don't know what's happening

Comment: I guess some more context is needed.. does the generated C code compile without warnings and s oforth...

Comment: By any chance would `$4` be referring to the same `str` buffer that you are `sprintf`ing into?

Comment: Please provide the actual generated C code for these parts.

Comment: Provide the full bison rule, not just the actions.